# printf of 'Float' type returns wrong value

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to printf the following number:

```
Float val = 500.5080;

printf("%f",val);
```

Why the printed value i'm getting is **`500.507996`** ? I will be glad for a detailed explanation.

Comment: See the duplicate. Yes this is bewildering when you first encounter it. Nothing wrong with the way you've posed the question though.

Comment: Detailed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point :D