# Return printf val of float of type char *str

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357663/printf-of-float-type-returns-wrong-value)

Function should return  `printf` value of `float` of type  `char str*`

**Inputs:**

```
char *string = "%f";
float k = 1.0005325678910
```

**Function:**

My function takes input string `%f` and float value `1.0005325678910`
 as inputs storing the value of `printf` in `char *answer`.Here I am unable to allocate memory for `char *answer`

```
int length(char* string){
     int i = 0;
     while (string[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return i;
 }

 char *res(char *string, float k){
      int len = length(string); //len is a function which return length of the string
      char *answer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
      sprintf(answer,format, n);
      //printf("%05d", 50);
      //printf("%s", sqlAnswers);
     return answer;
 }
```

**Expected Output:**

```
char *output =  1.000532;
```

**Bug:**
  allocation of memory to `char *answer`
  Output: 1.000533

My code should not round the last digit.

**Edit:**
Ex: If my `float k = 6.143211` then  **expected Output** should be `6.14` but the function `returns 6.15` which rounds the last digit.

Comment: You have forgotten that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte string*. And that you need space for the *null-terminator* as well.

Comment: As for your question, please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us. And read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). There's no question anywhere, there's no explanation about your "bug", or what happens with the code you show, or what should happen. Etc.

Comment: You are assuming that the string passed is the right size for the output of  `sprintf`. What does `len(string);` have to do with it?

Comment: Also, note that the specifier `"%2f"` does *not* prevent the output of `sprintf` overflowing.

Comment: `int len = len(string);` is *highly* confusing. Don't do this.

Comment: I updated len(string) as length(string)

Comment: By definition `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Comment: @coder: The conversion of 6.143211 is a separate issue and should be asked in a separate question that includes a [mcve]. Please do not edit questions to change the basic question asked or to insert additional questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Will not do that again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are trying to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *res(char *format, float k)
{
    //  Ask snprintf to report how many bytes are needed.
    int t = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, k);
    if (t < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Encoding error.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Allocate space for those bytes and a null terminator.
    char *result = malloc(t+1);
    if (!result)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation error.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Format the number.
    snprintf(result, t+1, format, k);

    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *b = res("%f", 1.0005325678910);

    puts(b);

    free(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general C way to do this is to pass in a char * buf and size_t len. Then return how many chars have been or would have been written to the buffer.

But if you want to write a function that allocates a buffer of the right size you have 2 choices:

1) always allocate the maximum size for "%2f". Given the size that's probably the best. It's not worth the CPU overhead to compute the right size to save a byte here or there.

2) find out the right length using:

```
char c;
int len = snprintf(&c, 1, "%2f, k);
assert(len >= 0);
++len;
```

or output to a fixed sized buffer and then use strdup(). Sort of a combination of 1 and 2.